# onClick & What argument to put inside increment()?

Tags: android, kotlin

I wish the amount to increase by 1 every time the "+" is clicked.

[image]

But now when I click "+", it shows like this

[image]

Problem(A): increment is red in  `android:onClick="increment" />`   in activity_main.xml

Problem(B): I know I should write something inside () of `increment()` and I have tried  (1)`increment(view: View?)`=> red alert: `parameter 'view' is never used` shows up, but Problem (A) will be solved.

`increment(view: View?)` is modified from java codes.

```
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }
```

if I replace (view: View?) with something else then red alert: `parameter 'view' is never used` disappears.
(2)`increment(number:Int)`(3)`increment()`
None of them works. (2)(3) will result `Unfortunately, Order Coffee has stopped.`

Here is my MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var amount: Int=2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun increment() {
        amount++
        display(amount)
    }
    //This method is called when the order button is clicked.
    fun submitOrder() {
        var amount: Int=2
        display(amount)
        displayPrice(amount*10)
    }
    fun decrement() {
        amount--
        display(amount)
    }
    //This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     private fun display(number: Int) {
        val amountTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.amount_text_view) as TextView
        amountTextView.text = "" + number
    }
    /**
     * This method displays the given price on the screen.
     */
    private fun displayPrice(number: Int) {
        val priceTextView = findViewById<View>(R.id.price_text_view) as TextView
        priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number))
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't use  the ``view`` parameter in your ``onClick`` method, you can ignore the warning (it's just a cleanup hint, it should be yellow not red). The reason your app is stopping is because it's crashing, so you'll need to post the stacktrace from Logcat (something like ``Exception caused by`` and everything that comes after it, that'll explain what's going wrong). But it sounds like it's just that your ``increment`` function doesn't have the ``view`` parameter?

Comment: You are quick and you solved my problem. You should post the answer and I will accept your answer. Actually I wrote ```increment(view: View?)``` and it was crashing so I thought what I wrote was wrong. Thank you for your quick help. Its frustrated for beginners to always doubt myself.

Comment: No worries! There's a lot of little things like that to pick up, it just comes with experience

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Stacktrace is a report in Logcat tab located in the bottom of the Android Studio screen that shows the active stack frames with time during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you don't use the view parameter in your onClick method, you can ignore the warning - it's just a cleanup hint, it should be yellow not red. (It's also wrong in this case, because you know you need that `View` parameter! The compiler doesn't know about the `onClick` attribute in the XML though, so it thinks it's unused)

If it says the app has stopped, that's a crash and there should be an error log saying where it crashed and why - the crashes you're getting are probably because you're changing the signature of your `onClick` function. An `onClickListener` has a single `View` parameter, so whatever function you use has to match that.

Because you're saying "look for a function called *this* and use that as the click listener" in your XML file, it doesn't know what that function's going to be until you run the app and try clicking a thing. If you want to do it in code instead, you can do:

```
plusButton.setOnClickListener() { increment() }
```

which technically still has the `View` passed in, as a variable called `it` by default, but we're not using it so we can just ignore it! I prefer doing things in code like this personally, setting it in XML is kinda brittle and unhelpful sometimes (like you've discovered) but it's just a personal choice really

Comment: Something in your answer that I don't understand. (1) I don't have a function called _this_. (2)`plusButton.setOnClickListener() { increment() }`  What is the `View` passed in and what is `it`? (3) Where to put `plusButton.setOnClickListener() { increment() }`

Comment: I meant in your XML you're just giving it the name of a function to use, but it doesn't know what ``Activity`` or ``Fragment`` the layout is going to be used in, so it can't check if a function with that name exists until the app is actually running. If you want to try setting things up in code, you should probably follow a tutorial like this one: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interactivity?hl=pt-br#6 It's important to know, at least - you'll need to do it at some point!

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.